# Netlogo GIS coordinate transformation issue

Tags: gis, netlogo

I want to export to raster a NetLogo simulation output based on shp files, using:

```
to export-GIS
  let patches_out nobody
  ask one-of patches [set patches_out gis:patch-dataset pcolor]
  gis:store-dataset patches_out (word "usos" ".asc")
end
```

but it outputs:

```
Extension exception: you must define a coordinate transformation before using any other GIS features
error while patch 17 -10 running GIS:PATCH-DATASET
  called by procedure EXPORT-GIS
  called by Button 'export-GIS'
```

How can this coordinate transformation be defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue adding the following lines at the Setup phase:

```
set envelope gis:load-dataset "data/land.shp"
gis:set-world-envelope gis:envelope-of envelope
```